# Bad request (400) on Django Localhost

Tags: python, django, server, localhost, bad-request

I have the project successfully deployed through AWS. However, I would like to make some changes and experiment on them using `localhost:8000/` first before making the changes to AWS server. I set my settings.py to: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP address', 'www.website.com']` to deploy it. Though, I also want to be able to run the server in my local computer so I can experiment it before showing to public. The url is `(r^homepage$')` When I go to `localhost:8000/homepage`, it gives a Bad Request (400). I tried many permutations of the urls but nothing works.

Comment: you can set Debug=True to see the error message

Comment: It worked. I was able to see the error message and add 'localhost' to Allowed Hosts. Thank you, Ekrem!

Comment: I post it as an answer so others can see it please approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set Debug=True to see the error message.

Comment: it didnt help me; no details.